# Can we add controls to the status bar on iOS?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-ios

I am working on a MAUI Hybrid app and using Razor components for the interface.

On IOS, I have hidden the status bar and disable the safe area.

Now, I'd like to have controls display in the status bar, on the iPhone 14 (for example).
Here is a visualization of where I want to move two icons on the right side.

[image: Visualization of where to move the icons to]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It is not possible to add custom controls to the status bar on iOS.  The status bar is reserved for displaying system icons and information, such as the time, battery level, and network status.